# Change duration of Live update in Metro UI apps Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, modern-ui

I do not know the english translation of it but for example the contacts app and news app in Metro UI that rolls up news and images every ~5 second.

How do I change the duration so it updates just for about every 30 seconds. Or even better, if I could change so it updates each time I leave the start panel and returns.

Comment: If you can slow it down, it would be possible to speed it up as well, which might hammer servers of apps that have been deliberately set to update at a certain interval by the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the duration or speed of Live Tile updates. You can only enable or disable updates.

As Ramhound points out in the comment below, developers of live tiles have a certain amount of control over the frequency of refreshes, but this isn't a property that is exposed to end users.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-winapps/how-to-make-windows-8-live-tiles-update-more-often/d70df53c-0942-415f-948c-9199935803a5)

Comment: It can be changed, just not by the user, but by the author of the application in question.  There are limits of course, to prevent, bad behavior.

Comment: When I said "you", I was referring to the OP, who wanted to know if he could change the update frequency as an end-user. I edited my answer to include the distinction.

Answer (score 3):

Live tiles can show up to 5 different pieces of content in a single update. These are queued up and cycled through on a schedule that the developer does NOT control. However, updates to the live tiles are controlled by the developer in three ways:

1. The application, while running, can update the tiles
2. The tiles, periodically, can refresh themselves from a URL
3. A background task can update tiles no more frequently than every 15 minutes
4. A cloud service can push updates no more than 500 times a day

The user can disable the "live" part of a tile. However, the behavior of the tile if "live" cannot be otherwise controlled. And in many ways, even the developer is limited in his ability to control them.

I think your English was just fine.