# How can I limit internet bandwidth used by live tile updates?

Tags: windows-8, live-tiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change duration of Live update in Metro UI apps Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/498602/change-duration-of-live-update-in-metro-ui-apps-windows-8)

I don't want my apps which are not important to me to use much of my internet, For e.g. for my  weather app it will be enough if gets updated once in every 6 hours. Is there any setting for this?